# Adding two timestamps to a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, timestamp

I currently am adding a column with the timestamp to an existing dataframe in my Spark script. It looks like this:

```
val log = Source.fromArg(args, "log").read 
var added = log.withColumn("time_added", lit(unix_timestamp()))
```

This produces a new column in the output called time_added with the timestamp.

I now want to add two timestamps (one for when the thing was added, and one for the current timestamp)

However, adding the line:

```
var int = log.withColumn("new", lit(unix_timestamp()))
```

This produces only one new column called "new", but there is no longer a column called time_added.

Is there a way to produce two new columns with two different timestamps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you have to use the already added dataframe to add the new column - `added`.

```
val df = Seq("a").toDF()

val added = df.withColumn("time_added", lit(unix_timestamp()))
val addednew = added.withColumn("new", lit(unix_timestamp() + 100))

newtimeDF.show(false)

//OR

val added2 = df.withColumn("time_added", lit(unix_timestamp())).withColumn("new", lit(unix_timestamp() + 100))
addtimedf2.show(false)

+-----+----------+----------+
|value|time_added|new       |
+-----+----------+----------+
|a    |1528398456|1528398556|
+-----+----------+----------+
```